# How to build boost libraries using cmake

Tags: boost, build, cmake

I am trying to build boost using cmake as mentioned [here].(https://svn.boost.org/trac10/wiki/CMakeConfigAndBuild)
 
The issue is that the [repo](http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/branches/release) does not contain any `CMakeLists.txt`.

What am I missing?

Comment: Good question. I don't think that you are missing anything; `boost` seems to be missing a`CMakeLists.txt` file.  Note, the page you referenced is over 10 years old. Nowadays, the recommended  way to build `boost` is using `b2` not `cmake`, see: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html.

Comment: Great... I found this meanwhile: `https://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/branches/CMake/release/` which has a `CMakeLists.txt` but is still not able to build due to some errors.

Comment: I think it's an old repo. The main `boost` repo is [here](https://github.com/boostorg/boost) on GutHub which doesn't have a `CMakeLists.txt` file. It's shame, as `cmake` is the de-facto standard `c++` build tool, even supported by `Qt` who have their own `qmake` tool, but not by `boost`...

Comment: If you're using cmake, you could also use vcpkg which allows you to build boost and then include it in your cmake project easily.

Comment: Including `boost` in my `cmake` projects was not an issue, `find_package` works fine, I just wanted to build with `cmake` for consistency, but `vcpkg` looks interesting, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is not possible unless you decide to make your own `CMakeLists.txt`.
I just went with `b2` in my case as `cmake` was not a fixed requirement.